# My API URL is Correct and the HTTP(S) is Correct, but Console.log() Comes up Blank? Why?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, jsonp, access-control

I can't get any API urls to work! All of my JavaScript code is correct, so I don't know what the problem is.

My CodePen console and Google Chrome developer console is blank!
See screenshot here:https://s25.postimg.org/k5ds4p1xb/Console_Test.jpg
[(Screenshot of consoles)](https://s25.postimg.org/k5ds4p1xb/Console_Test.jpg)

Here is my CodePen:
https://codepen.io/IDCoder/full/KZqNdr/

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var quote;

  function getNewQuote() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?',
      jsonp: 'jsonp',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {
        method: 'getQuote',
        lang: 'en',
        format: 'jsonp'
      },
      success: function(response) {
        //quote = response.quoteText;
        console.log(response.quoteText);


      }
    });
  }
  //getNewQuote();
});

 //getNewQuote();

 // $('.get-quote').on('click', function(e) {
  //  e.preventDefault();
   // getNewQuote();
  //});

  //$('#quote').text(response.quoteText);
        //if (response.quoteAuthor) {
          //$('#author').text('said by ' + response.quoteAuthor);
        //} else {
         // $('#author').text('- unknown');
        //}
```

A commenter recommended I use an ajax error call and I implemented that and got the Google Chrome developer console to log this **"Failed to load https://codepen.io/boomerang/iFrameKey-a33d8144-0d32-5d95-7476-4d00493149e7/wrongfile.txt: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404."**    ....I'm confused!

Comment: Ummm...did you consider adding an error handler?

Comment: "An error handler"? Nope! Have never done that before? How would I do that?

Comment: Read the documentation for `$.ajax`

Comment: You are duplicating query parameters, use this url: `https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/` or remove `data` property from ajax

Comment: @YouneL, whether I take out the data property from ajax or switch the API urls, I still get the same thing: blank consoles....I have another CodePen here: [https://codepen.io/IDCoder/pen/NwNOgq?editors=1010] where the API works, so I don't know what the problem is with this one!

Comment: @charlietfl, do you mean something like this `function handleAjaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // do something
}

$.ajax({
  
    success: function() { },
    error: handleAjaxError
});`

Comment: yes....exactly. Note however that jsonp requests are actually script requests. Error handling is not as robust as for regular ajax

Comment: You need to add simple error callback function https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax_error

Comment: @charlietfl, oh ok! So the error-handling might not work lol... :(

Comment: Did you even try it?

Comment: @charlietfl `function handleAjaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
 
}

 $.ajax({url: "wrongfile.txt", error: function(xhr){
            alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }});`  
I put the above code and get these error messages: see link for screenshot [https://s25.postimg.org/z1cbcp5qn/Console_Test_2.jpg]

Comment: Looks like you are using `http` in your code pen but posted `https` here on stack overflow.

Comment: @HMR, even when I tried one with `https`, it was still giving problems.....working on it...never thought **APIs** could be so much damn trouble!

Comment: You can copy the $.ajax block on this page in the console and see it works. Maybe its something specific to codepen

Comment: @HMR, there's no `ajax` block on this page except the one I posted, unless you're referring to another page. Also, this guy's CodePen works ([https://codepen.io/krjordan/pen/oXRQXG?editors=1010]), and he's using the same API that I'm using: `https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?` makes no sense!

Comment: Copy `$.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?',
      jsonp: 'jsonp',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {
        method: 'getQuote',
        lang: 'en',
        format: 'jsonp'
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response.quoteText);


      }
    });` press F12, click console, paste, press enter.

Comment: @charlietfl, guess what I found out? That `$.ajax` error thingy (`function handleAjaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { } $.ajax({url: "wrongfile.txt", error: function(xhr){ alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText); }});`) is wrong, because I tried it in the following working CodePen at [codepen.io/krjordan/pen/oXRQXG?editors=1010], and the Google Chrome developer's console gives the same error as it gives in mine, even though his is working! Wow!

Comment: @HMR, about to try that right now.....it works in the console!

Comment: Forked the codepen, Changed `http` to `https` and uncommented the `getNewQuote();` line, works fine. Maybe it's time for you to take a break stuff like this happens sometimes when you can't see the obvious anymore. codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wpPYyJ

Comment: @HMR, it works!! see the link to screenshot: [https://s25.postimg.org/hf91lf2dr/Console_Test_3.jpg] .....now I just have to connect the buttons! Thanks a million! And you're probably right because I been at theis for maybe 6 hours non-stop lol

Comment: @HMR, give this post an upvote! I need the reputation lol ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the protocol to `https` on the codepen and uncommented `getNewQuote();`